# How to add buttons to dojo titlepane

Tags: dojo, titlebar

Is there any way to add **buttons** to **TitlePane** header(right side of title bar), so that i can do some operations(download,delete...)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the documentation, you could supply a dijit Widget as a content of TitlePane.

Comment: And I believe, that the TitlePane widget can be extended.

Comment: Did you get answer to this question? Is there no attribute that we can use in the declartive form to append content to the titlePane?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is.  I was able to do it using the .placeAt() method in the added dijit's creation, such as below:

In index.htm

```
<div id="divMap"></div>
```

In main.js within callback

```
ready (function() {
    var ttpMyTitlePane = new TitlePane({
        title: 'My Title'
    });
    divMenu.appendChild(ttpMyTitlePane.domNode);

    var btnMyButton = new Button({
        label: 'ButtonText',
        onClick: function() {
            // do stuff
        } 
    }).placeAt(ttpMyTitlePane.domNode);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

dijit TitlePane header contains the following

```
<div class="dijitTitlePaneTitleFocus" data-dojo-attach-point="focusNode" aria-pressed="true" role="button" aria-controls="dijit_TitlePane_0_pane" tabindex="0">
<span data-dojo-attach-point="arrowNode" class="dijitInline dijitArrowNode" role="presentation"></span><span data-dojo-attach-point="arrowNodeInner" class="dijitArrowNodeInner">-</span><span data-dojo-attach-point="titleNode" class="dijitTitlePaneTextNode" style="user-select: none;">Rule</span>
<span class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitButton" role="presentation" widgetid="dijit_form_Button_1">
<span class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonNode" data-dojo-attach-event="ondijitclick:__onClick" role="presentation">
<span class="dijitReset dijitStretch dijitButtonContents" data-dojo-attach-point="titleNode,focusNode" role="button" aria-labelledby="dijit_form_Button_1_label" tabindex="0" id="dijit_form_Button_1" style="user-select: none;">
<span class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitIcon dijitNoIcon" data-dojo-attach-point="iconNode"></span><span class="dijitReset dijitToggleButtonIconChar"></span>
<span class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonText" id="dijit_form_Button_1_label" data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode">x</span></span></span></span>
</div>
```

As you see there are several attach points we can reference.

To add any item, even a dijit or custom widget do the following to place items after the last in the **focusNode** attach point (note: you have to style it correctly in order for items to appear in the position you want)

```
        var myTitlePane = new TitlePane({ title: "TitlePane" });            

        var deleteButton = new Button({
            label: 'x',
            onClick: function () {
                //do something here like delete the titlepane
                //alert();
            }
        });
        deleteButton.placeAt(rulesTitlePane.focusNode);
```

This will produce something that looks like this,

[image]

Or you can replace everything and create whatever you want in the focusNode.